# Finding Unique Values across many columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I'm working on what I thought would be a simple task that has become quite complicated.

In Column A, I have a Field Name.  In columns B through ANV (1059 columns) I have values associated with that field.  I'd like to count how many unique values there are associated with the item in Column A.  As an added layer of complexity, Column A contains duplicates.

I have a decent idea on how to account for the Column A duplicates, but looking for unique values across 1059 columns keeps getting me #VALUE! errors or DIV0s

I am trying SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(data,data&"")) as explainedd https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif

Does anybody have any suggestions?

(also, for bonus points, ideally i wanted to make a pivot table that would list and count every value associated with the item in Column A, grouping the duplicates together as it did so -- this also turned out to be more complicated than i expected, so i ditched that approach -- any instruction on that would be hugely appreciated)

Thank you, everybody!

Answer (score 0):

What about PowerQuery? With Excel 2010 and above you can use this rather powerful tool.

> ***Warning:*** My Excel is in Dutch so please excuse any mistakes in how menus and options might be called :). Anyone can feel free to correct me on this!

For example purposes I will use the below sample data:

[image]

- Select your data > Data > From Data/Range > Choose whether you have headers or not.

This will open PQ-Editor.

[image]

- Select column 1 > Transform tab > Unpivot other tables

This will create a list. Assuming you head headers, there should be three columns.

[image]

- Select column 1 and column 2 > Start tab > Remove rows > Doublures

The list should have shrunken, the doubles have disappeared.

[image]

- Select column 1 > Start tab > Group > group on column A, confirm

You should be left with two columns, one of all unique values in column A, one with the count of unique values over all the other columns associated with column A.

[image]

You can now exit PQ and save your work. This should create another table with the above data on your worksheet.

[image]

Would that be along of what you had in mind to count unique values associated with the first column?

Comment: @kyledawson, have you managed to solve your problem yet?